# Config class not found if my file is in autoload

Tags: php, laravel

I just put my GlobalConstant.php file in autoload array in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files":[
            "app/Http/Controllers/GloabalConstants.php"
        ]
    }
```

now if i am using config('app.url') in my constant file it gives me error like given below
[image]

Comment: Why have you added it to the `files` autoloader? It is within the `app` directory so it will already be PSR-4 auto-loaded.

Comment: @GeorgeHanson without putting that file in file array it will not autoload gloabally

Comment: How are you trying to use it though? You should just be able to add the namespace to the PHP file you are using it in and use the class that way.

Comment: i am using like 

<?php

$url = config('app.url');

Comment: i think it not working because autoload loads first than bootstrap

Comment: No, I mean how are you using `app/Http/Controllers/GloabalConstants.php` that means you have to load it within the `files` auto-loader?

Comment: yes and it also loads but problem is i am not able to use any config in my autoloaded constant file